# Server side file picker for Business Catalyst WebApp

Tags: jquery, web-applications, business-catalyst, filepicker

When writing our own WebApps in Business Catalyst, how can we present a file picker dialog box so the user can select a file which exists on the server and optionally upload a file to the server from that same dialog?

Business Catalyst have their own implementation of this in the WebApp admin interface and I wonder if we can hook into this. I assume it will be a matter of including a JS file (or multiple files) and then a jQuery function to hook into this.

Can we use BC's file picker?

If not, how would I go about it as I assume I would need to provide some sort of ASP connector to do the work of gathering the file/folder lists which I am assuming would not be possible to do.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is possible.

You *may* be able to use the [BC API](http://docs.businesscatalyst.com/reference/rest-apis/file-system/get-folder-content.html) to create some sort of workaround but this isn't something I have much experience with.

As for uploading a file, you can have a field for image upload and allow a user to upload an image.

Comment: I already have the ability to "upload" an image and that all works. However, what I want is the ability to pop-up a form allowing selection of files **on the server**. I have played around with their API and I have been able to use the File and Folder classes to return a list of files to allow selection, so this basically works, but I will have to spend a lot of time to make all of this pretty and user friendly. If I was able to use BC's own file selection tool it would be simple. Sounds like BC does not allow us to use the tools that they themselves use.

Comment: @David - Unfortunately, I believe that this is your only option: `I have played around with their API and I have been able to use the File and Folder classes to return a list of files to allow selection`.